# x230 upgrade, keep losing wifi (internal card, dongle)

Tags: networking, wifi, thinkpad, coreboot

I am having incredible trouble with networking. ([original post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/cmkua9/x230_missing_connectivity_2_motherboards_2_wifi/), different forum).

I'm upgrading a secondhand Thinkpad x230 (installed: coreboot with SeaBIOS, have run me_cleaner, using Lubuntu Cosmic).

Suddenly, internal wifi refuses to work. Stopped inexplicably 3  weeks ago after I reassembled the machine (keyboard, etc). Tried a different motherboard (original config), booted live USBs (Fedora, Manjaro, etc), traced antenna wires and different wifi card (2nd hand). No joy.

- Wifi sometimes works with a DWA-131 Dlink "Wireless N Nano USB Adapter", but usually not.
- A Huawei 4G modem seems to work perfectly, recognized as a wired ethernet connection.
- Not sure, but DWA-131 adapter seems to start working after the 4G modem has been inserted.

My last [dmsesg dump is here](https://pastebin.com/C2KvWYs5), if that's of any use. (Timestamp is wrong, so clock is out, apparently). The last few hours shows me plugging and unplugging things (including a computer-to-computer ethernet link, below), and the DWA-131 adapter starting to work somehow.

Really not sure how to proceed.

---

There's another issue I'll post separately: a cable connection from the x230 to a Dell XPS13 prompted a strange network in someone else's name.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Lubuntu 19 and things are working.

(No disassembly of the hardware, not even much movement on the desk - just plugged in the usb with the distro .iso and, hey presto, instant function.)

I don't know *why* things stopped working on 18.10 (or live usbs of Manjaro, Fedora, etc), but, for now, I can use my internal wifi card as it was always supposed to be.